# bcp out default sorting with first and last row par

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to export a large table using bcp. I get the count of the table, then divide that by 250k, then run one bcp export for each batch. (it's much faster this way)

```
bcp my_table out c:\filepath1 -F 0 -L 249999
bcp my_table out c:\filepath2 -F 250000 -L 499999
bcp my_table out c:\filepath3 -F 500000 -L 749999
etc
```

How does it know to sort these all the same way? What's the default sort of a bcp export?

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that running `SELECT blah FROM table` cannot guarantee the ordering of the rows, doing a bcp at the table level also cannot guarantee any ordering.

To achieve this I think you would need to use the "[query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utilityhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15&view=sql-server-ver15#system-requirements)" option of the bcp utility and craft the query to make us of an `ORDER BY`  clause and then use `OFFSET and FETCH` to get the rows.